# How to get the time format I need?

Tags: sql, oracle, date-format

At the moment I get a date in this format:

```
2019-10-07
```

That is, it looks like this

```
TO_CHAR("DATE_BEGIN", 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

How to do so in order to receive a date in this format:

```
Wed Oct 07 2019 00:00:00 GMT 0500
```

I tried to do so:

```
 TO_CHAR("DATE_BEGIN", 'DY MON DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS') like '%Wed Aug 28 2019 00:00:00 GMT 0500%'
```

But something is missing, because it does not work.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh Oracle DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the format you'd like :

```
select to_char( systimestamp at time zone 'GMT','Dy Mon dd yyyy hh24:mi:ss TZR') 
  from dual;
```

or directly use :

```
select to_char( systimestamp,'Dy Mon dd yyyy hh24:mi:ss TZR') 
  from dual;
```

or for your current substitution date use a casting :

```
select to_char( cast( date'2019-10-07' as timestamp) at time zone 'GMT',
                      'Dy Mon dd yyyy hh24:mi:ss TZR') 
  from dual;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1bc5d881e767ebdb07866098f05d83a7)</kbd>

Comment: I added a demo @user12094588

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you can return both `GMT` and the `0500`.  This should get you close:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'GMT', 'Dy Mon DD YYYY HH:MI:SS TZR') 
FROM dual
```

Result:

```
Mon Oct 07 2019 08:24:44 +00:00
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0215b/86)

Comment: MI for minutes, not MM (which is *months*).